# How to send a reply using Google My Business API

Tags: google-my-business-api

Has anyone worked with the Google My Business API?

If yes: How do I send a reply via the API?

By PUT method I send the request to the address indicated in the documentation:

[https://mybusiness.googleapis.com/…/X…/reviews/XXXXXXX/reply](https://mybusiness.googleapis.com/%E2%80%A6/X%E2%80%A6/reviews/XXXXXXX/reply)

And returns

```
{
   "error":"error"   "code":400,
   "message":"Request contains an invalid argument.",
   "status":"INVALID_ARGUMENT",
   "details":[
      {
         "@type":"type.googleapis.com/google.mybusiness.v4.ValidationError",
         "errorDetails":[
            {
               "code":2,
               "message":"Reply text is missing from the request."
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
}
```

How I did not try to follow this text but when I add the parameter I switch to 404.

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Look like **comment** field is missing.

Example request:

```
curl --location --request PUT 'https://mybusiness.googleapis.com/v4/accounts/{account-id}/locations/{location-id}/reviews/{review-id}/reply' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer {example-token}' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{
    "comment": "This is reply."
}'
```

Note - replace next tokens to yours:

- account-id
- location-id
- review-id
- example-token

Documentation: https://developers.google.com/my-business/reference/rest/v4/accounts.locations.reviews#reviewreply